# Alfresco Add Workflow Hyperlink to Notification

Tags: notifications, workflow, alfresco

When it comes time to "evaluate" the outcome of a workflow.  The workflow creator gets a task to do so.  They would then need to open the workflow through "workflows I've started" to see the whole thing.
What I would like to do is add a hyperlink to the notification that would take them to either the Task Assigned or to the Workflow itself.
I believe this can be done by adding a couple of lines to the wf-email.html.ftl.
I'm just unsure of the syntax.
"Evaluating" is where it's most needed, but should be fine its included in all notifications.

Thanks!
-Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but can you try this:

```
<a href="${shareUrl}/page/task-edit?taskId=${args.workflowId}">
```

Comment: Thank you, but no, it didn't quite work.  I'm guessing there's a second part missing after the line you posted.